# Oracle How to find Debug Compiled Stored Procedures/Functions

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, system-tables

How can I get list of stored procedures/Function which are compiled for debug?

I do not see relevant column in following tables.

- DBA_PROCEDURES
- DBA_OBJECTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for Phil's answer, following query do what I need, compile all debug compiled objects.

```
SELECT 'ALTER ' || object_type || ' ' || owner || '.' || object_name || '     compile;'
FROM   SYS.ALL_PROBE_OBJECTS
WHERE DEBUGINFO = 'T'
ORDER BY owner, object_type, object_name;
```

Answer (score 6):

I think DBA_PLSQL_OBJECT_SETTINGS gives more appropriate information.

Comment: What is difference? Does it give me more information?

Comment: it not only tells you if it has been debug enabled, also gives you special compiler flags used (if any).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the documented way:

ALL_PLSQL_OBJECT_SETTINGS view, PLSQL_DEBUG column

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17615/refrn20385.htm#REFRN20385

Answer (score 2):

Look in `SYS.ALL_PROBE_OBJECTS`. The `DEBUGINFO` column contains a `T` (true) or `F` (false) indicating whether it was compiled in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

just for future supplementary info

```
SELECT PO.OWNER,PO.OBJECT_NAME,PO.OBJECT_TYPE,PO.DEBUGINFO
,'ALTER ' || REPLACE(object_type,'PACKAGE BODY','PACKAGE') || ' ' || owner || '.' || object_name ||DECODE(object_type,'PACKAGE BODY',' COMPILE BODY;',' COMPILE;') COPILE_NO_DEBUG
,'ALTER ' || REPLACE(object_type,'PACKAGE BODY','PACKAGE') || ' ' || owner || '.' || object_name ||DECODE(object_type,'PACKAGE BODY',' COMPILE DEBUG BODY;',' COMPILE DEBUG;') COPILE_WITH_DEBUG
FROM   SYS.ALL_PROBE_OBJECTS PO
--WHERE OBJECT_NAME='YOUR_DEFINITION_PKG' AND DEBUGINFO IN ('F','T')
ORDER BY owner, object_type, object_name;
```